# Как правильно перейти на pdo, Fatal error: Uncaught exception?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Добрый день, разбираясь в бд, решил что логичнее юзать `pdo`, хочу перевести свою несложную форму авторизации с `mysqli` на `pdo`, и буквально сразу посыпались проблемы(я оставил закомментированный код с `mysqli`)

подключение :

```js
  require 'app_config.php';

  //$mysql=mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD) or die("<p>Ошибка к подключению БД :" .
  //    mysqli_error($mysql) . "</p>");
  //mysqli_select_db($mysql, DATABASE_NAME) or die("<p>Ошибка при выборе БД</p>" . mysqli_error($mysql) );
  //Через pdo DATABASE HANDLE

  //$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=DATABASE_HOST;dbname=DATABASE_USERNAME", DATABASE_NAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD);
  $DBH = new PDO('mysql:dbname=ch33404_testdb;host=localhost', 'DATABASE_USERNAME', 'DATABASE_PASSWORD');
  $DBH - > setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

вот так выдает больше ошибок, не пойму почему :

> //$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=DATABASE_HOST;dbname=DATABASE_USERNAME",
>   DATABASE_NAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD);

суть: есть простая штмл форма с полями, скрипт create_user.php должен отработать и записать пользователя в базу, сейчас после нажатия "залогиниться" вылетает такая ошибка

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'DATABASE_USERNAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in
>   /home/c/ch33404/testsite/public_html/test/scripts/database_connection.php:15
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/c/ch33404/testsite/public_html/test/scripts/database_connection.php(15):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=ch...', 'DATABASE_USERNA...',
>   'DATABASE_PASSWO...') #1
>   /home/c/ch33404/testsite/public_html/test/scripts/create_user.php(3):
>   require('/home/c/ch33404...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/c/ch33404/testsite/public_html/test/scripts/database_connection.php
>   on line 15

---

вот сам скрипт create_user.php:

```css
<?php require'database_connection.php';
 $first_name=trim($_REQUEST['first_name']);
 $last_name=trim($_REQUEST['last_name']);
 $email=trim($_REQUEST['email']);
 $bio=trim($_REQUEST['bio']);
 $vkontakte_url=str_replace("vk.com",
"vkontakte.com",
trim($_REQUEST['vkontakte_url']));
 $position=strpos($vkontakte_url,
"vk.com");
 if ($position===false) {
  $vkontakte_url="http://www.vk.com/" . $vkontakte_url;
}
$twitter_handle=trim($_REQUEST['twitter_handle']);
 $twitter_url="http://www.twitter.com/";
 $position=strpos($twitter_handle,
"@");
 if ($position===false) {
  $twitter_url=$twitter_url . $twitter_handle;
}
else {
  $twitter_url=$twitter_url . substr($twitter_handle, $position + 1);
}
////через mysqli
//$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, bio, vkontakte_url, twitter_handle) " . "VALUES ('{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}', '{$bio}' " .
//                      "'{$vkontakte_url}', '{$twitter_handle}');";
//
//Добавить пользователя  в базу данных
//mysqli_query($mysql,$insert_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysql));
//Вставка данных через PDO
$STH=$DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( first_name, last_name,email, bio, vkontakte_url, twitter_handle) values ( '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}', '{$bio}', '{$vkontakte_url}', '{$twitter_handle}' )");
 $STH->execute();
//Отправляем пользователя на свой профиль
//header("Location: show_user.php?user_id=" . mysqli_insert_id($mysql));
```

в 10 строке connection.php - это:

> $DBH = new PDO('mysql:dbname=ch33404_testdb;host=localhost',
>   'DATABASE_USERNAME', 'DATABASE_PASSWORD');

Comment: Из ошибки видно что доступ запрещен для пользователя. Скорее всего неправильно ввели имя пользователя или пароль от бд в 10 строке connection.php

Comment: немного в сторону: `$DBH - >` - `$DBH ->` (в стрелке пробела не должно быть)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый пользователь пхп, даже не являясь программистом, должен вырабатывать у себя привычку читать сообщения об ошибках. И - что немаловажно - читать целиком, а не только первые пару слов.

Обычно в сообщении об ошибке подробно написано, в чем состоит проблема.

Например, в данном случае нам пишет, что пользователь пытается авторизоваться с именем DATABASE_USERNAME, что выглядит довольно необычно, и больше похоже на название *константы*, чем на имя базы данных.

Переводим взгляд на вызывающий код и убеждаемся что да - константа зачем-то взята в кавычки, и в итоге передается не ее значение, а буквально строка DATABASE_USERNAME.

Если убрать кавычки, то подключение к PDO пройдет успешно.

Чтобы использовать константы в строке DSN, следует применять конкатенацию:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.DATABASE_NAME.';host='.DATABASE_HOST
```

И еще раз напоминаю о необходимости записывать в вышеприведенные константы правильные и актуальные значения.